# How can I return the preceding matching value based on a criteria?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft

How can I return the preceding matching value based on a criteria?

I want the cells in "Initial Balance" to show if there is an existing balance based on the name. I tried several functions but I can't get the quite exact function to make it work. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Superuser . Can you elaborate a bit more on the expected outcome? Where do you want to check it for an existing balance?

Answer (score 0):

This formula should work, but notice I did a slight rearrangement of your columns: `=XLOOKUP(B3,$B$2:B2,$E$2:E2,0,0,-1)`

[image]

I basically merged your amount column into the addition/deduction column. I renamed the Initial Balance to Starting Balance and renamed Current balance to Ending Balance. With this structure all that is needed is the `XLOOKUP` formula as noted

1. `B3` = lookup up value is the name you want to find
2. `$B$2:B2` = lookup array of where you want to find the name; noting anchoring of the first part of cell references and ending with the row above the desired name to match
3. `$E$2:E2` = return array $ amount you want to see in the cell; note anchoring
4. `0` = if not found parameter
5. `0` = the match mode parameter of 0 for exact match
6. `-1` = the search mode parameter of -1 to start from the bottome of the lookup array

Note a second formula in the ending balance column E `C3+D3` to add the values in column C and Column D